# How to create a general and specific key binding

Tags: key-bindings

How do I bind a key for general use, but differently for a specific mode, such as dired?

eg how would I resolve this?

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd F12) #'dired-up-directory)
(global-set-key (kbd F12) 'shell)

Comment: please consult the manual. this topic is easy to find

Comment: A link would be useful...

Comment: Have you tried the code you've posted? I think it may work after you fix the `kbd`.

Answer (score 0):

To globally bind a key, `keymap-global-set` function can be used:

```
(keymap-global-set "C-z" 'shell)
```

To bind a key for a specific mode, you should use a hook:

```
(add-hook 'texinfo-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (keymap-set texinfo-mode-map "C-c p"
                        'backward-paragraph)
            (keymap-set texinfo-mode-map "C-c n"
                        'forward-paragraph)))
            (keymap-set texinfo-mode-map "C-c C-x x" nil)
```

You can find more information in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hooks as in the other answer, you can achieve a different behavior of a function for specific modes by defining a single function which checks `major-mode` with `cond` and executes custom function for that mode.

For example, if you wanted to have a single binding for documentation at point but customize this for `emacs-lisp-mode` and `python-mode` you could use:

```
(defun help-for-major-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((equal major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode) (call-interactively 'helpful-at-point))
        ((equal major-mode 'python-mode) (call-interactively 'python-eldoc-at-point))
        (t (call-interactively 'counsel-dash-at-point)))
  )
```

The `t` part at the end is the default function. Note that you may not need the `call-interactively` for some functions - depends on the function.

More general way of conditional execution of a function (not necessarily based on major-mode - any condition) can be easily done with the `cmds!` macro from Doom Emacs (you can copy the `defmacro` definition, you don't have to run Doom). For example, if you wanted to have one function which works just like `other-window` but in the special case, if there's only one window, creates a new window by splitting and switches to it, you could use:

```
(cmds!
 (singlep (window-list))
 'split-window-vertically-and-other-window

 'other-window
 )
```

This can be then bound to any key the same way you bind `defun`s.